# Was Zoom's last act at the end of Escape from Earth-2 intentional?

Tags: dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

At the end of *Escape from Earth-2*, just when it looks it's all fine and dandy, Zoom:

> stretches his arm through the portal, phasing *through* Jay Garrick and pulls him back to Earth 2.

Now, nothing so far indicates we can see through a portal. So, did Zoom know  what he was getting at the other end, and if so, how?

If he didn't know what he was getting at the other end, why did he:

> let his arm un-phase enough for him to able to pull Jay back, which would mean Jay is, in all likelihood, dead? For all he knows, it could be Barry at the other end. Zoom does seem intent on keeping speedsters alive, after all.

Comment: It seems most likely that Zoom was blindly reaching through the portal out of desperation to grab whatever was on the other side.

Comment: @TheIronCheek Jay didn't travel through the portal. He was on the other side all along.

Comment: oh yeah, that's right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Apparently so

We get to sit down with Zoom in the episode "Versus Zoom", where he explains the scam:

> **Zoom:** I also knew that the only way to make Barry become faster was if you all witnessed your old pal Jay die.
>
> <sup>*The Flash* Season 2 Episode  18: "Versus Zoom"</sup>

He reveals later that he had planned this out with Jay:

> **Zoom:** Believe me, getting my time remnant to agree to me murdering him took a bit of convincing. But once he saw the, well, the genius in my plan, he was all for it.
> <sup>*The Flash* Season 2 Episode  18: "Versus Zoom"</sup>

Comment: I didn't notice you'd edited the answer until now, sorry for the delay!

Answer (score 1):

This is educated guesswork, but it may be too big for the comments section-

Assuming Welles-2's theories that Zoom wants Barry's speed/power/whatever and can't get it from a dead Barry are correct, he wouldn't risk killing Barry. We won't know until the next episode or even later, but there is the possibility Zoom could somehow see who was where on the other side of the breach; that in grabbing Jay before it could be closed he was giving them a reason to find another way back to Earth-2, so Barry could come to him. However, this is just a theory, and could sound to some like a needlessly convoluted plan even by super-villain standards.